# Htaccess rewrite rule doesn't match

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a custom CMS and in the htaccess file, i have this line :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(press)/[^\\_]*_([0-9]+)\\.html$ ./FO/scripts/myScript.php?id=$3&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If, directly in the url, i check `http://mywebsite.com/website/FO/scripts/myScript.php?id=4521&lang=en`, it's ok, my script works well.

But i don't know how can i activate the rule, I tried with : `http://mywebsite.com/website/en/press/4521.html` but no effect.

Do you have any ideas for the base URL to match this rule ?

Thanks !

EDIT : or maybe forget the `website folder`, like http://mywebsite.com/en/press/4521.html

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't seem right. Use this rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/press/([0-9]+)\.html$ FO/scripts/myScript.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Maybe forget the website folder.. i can't add this RewriteBase i have a lot of rules in my htaccess

Comment: In that case just take out `RewriteBase` line from your htaccess

Comment: and if i want to add my website folder in the rule, is it like RewriteRule ^website/([a-z]{2})/press/..... ?

Comment: Yes that's right. `RewriteRule ^website/([a-z]{2})/press/([0-9]+)\.html$ website/FO/scripts/myScript.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: My url is http://mydomain/website/en/press/1810.html but always no effect... i removed all rules, so this rule is the only one in my htaccess...

Comment: If `/website/` has .htaccess then this rule must be placed inside that htaccess and rule should be: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/press/([0-9]+)\.html$ FO/scripts/myScript.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`